# How Serialize single value by json.net?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am serializing the `Student` class using `json.net`.

I would like to add to the serialized object an attribute (called `cheak` that is not a member of the `Student` class.

This is class student:

```
public class Student 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Faculty")]
        public string FacultyName { get { return Faculty.name; } }
        public double AVG { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string EducationInfo { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MotherName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PersonalInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

json:

```
{
  "ID": 24,
  "Faculty": "engen ",
  "AVG": 3.0,
  "DateOfBirth": "1990-02-02T00:00:00",
  "EducationInfo": "GOOD",
  "FatherName": "EEWF",
  "FirstName": "FFEWR",
  "LastName": "ERF",
  "MotherName": "ERF",
  "Password": null,
  "PersonalInfo": "ERF",
}
```

I want to add the attribute "cheak" to the serialized object:

```
{
  **cheak:true
  "ID": 24,
  "Faculty": "engen ",
  "AVG": 3.0,
  "DateOfBirth": "1990-02-02T00:00:00",
  "EducationInfo": "GOOD",
  "FatherName": "EEWF",
  "FirstName": "FFEWR",
  "LastName": "ERF",
  "MotherName": "ERF",
  "Password": null,
  "PersonalInfo": "ERF",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be able to deserialize as well as serialize object I would Inherit Student onto a new class like this

```
public class StudentJson : Student 
{
    public bool cheak { get; set; }
}
```

You can then pass this to be serialized.